# MongoDb searching nested array between dateTimes using Robomongo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am very new to MongoDb and experimenting to see if I can use it to store time series data.

I have inserted the following data...

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5785f186ed936527c05efa10"),
"Timestamp" : ISODate("2006-07-13T07:42:00.000Z"),
"Label1" : "Lab1",
"Attr" : "atrr1",
"Readings" : [ 
    {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2006-07-13T07:42:06.355Z"),
        "Value" : "22"
    }, 
    {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2006-07-13T07:42:07.355Z"),
        "Value" : "22"
    }, 
    {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2006-07-13T07:42:08.355Z"),
        "Value" : "22"
    }, 
  ....
```

So, each document as the array Readings that hold DateTimes in 1 second intervals.

So, if I want to query between 2 datetimes, I am trying the following in the [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) query window...

```
db.getCollection('Timedata').find(
 {
 'Readings.DateTime':    
    { $gt: '2005-07-13 07:42:13.355Z',  $lt: '2010-07-13 07:42:13.355Z'}        
  })
```

However this always returns `Fetched 0 record(s) in 11ms` where as it should actually return them all.

My syntax must be incorrect, but I just cannot find what is wrong with it and how to search for datetimes in a nested array as I have here. Would anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('Timedata').find(
 {
 Readings: {
   $elemMatch: 
     {DateTime: 
        {
            $gt: ISODate('2005-07-13 07:42:13.355Z'),
            $lt: ISODate('2010-07-13 07:42:13.355Z')
        }
     }
  }   
});


db.getCollection('Timedata').aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
        Readings: {
           $elemMatch: 
             {DateTime: 
                {
                    $gt: ISODate('2005-07-13 07:42:13.355Z'),
                    $lt: ISODate('2010-07-13 07:42:13.355Z')
                }
             }
          } 
        }
    },
   {
      $project: {
         _id:1,
         Timestamp:1,
         Label1:1,
         Attr:1,
         Readings: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Readings",
               as: "item",
               cond: { 
                   $and: [
                        {$gt: [ "$$item.DateTime", ISODate('2006-07-13 07:00:13.355Z') ]},
                        {$lt: ["$$item.DateTime", ISODate('2010-07-15 07:42:13.355Z')]}
                   ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, works perfectly! I shall study up on this syntax, which is quite different to the way I thought I saw in some documentation.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have jumped the gun here.The above returns the whole documents that have any Readings within the time period, including readings that fall outside of the filter. Was hoping there was a way to also have the first and the last document just have the readings included within the time period. Would this be possible with doing "manually"?

Comment: Look at updated answer. Just change the dates in fields.

Comment: Great, Thankyou! Yes now the results are have filtered readings.