# get only searched fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I've following documents in my mongodb collection:

```
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("579493bccdba841a0bf5ad1a"),
       "uniqueId": "bUbOaciS1g",
       "chat": [
         {
           "TS": ISODate("2016-07-24T10:09:00.631Z"),
           "user_ques": "hi",
           "rep_ans": "hello" 
        },
         {
           "TS": ISODate("2016-08-01T10:09:40.814Z"),
           "user_ques": "how are you?",
           "rep_ans": "i am fine"
        },
         {
           "TS": ISODate("2016-08-04T10:09:55.724Z"),
           "user_ques": "help me",
           "rep_ans": "sure"
        }
]
    }
    {
       "_id": ObjectId("579493bccdba841a0bf5ad1b"),
       "uniqueId": "xyzOaciS1g",
       "chat": [
         {
           "TS": ISODate("2016-08-09T10:09:00.631Z"),
           "user_ques": "hi",
           "rep_ans": "hello" 
        }
]
    }
```

what i want to do is get only fields with the specific dates and exclude others.
query i tried:

```
db.collection.find({'chat.TS':{$gte:ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:ISODate("2016-08-10T00:00:00.000Z")}}).pretty()
```

result i expected:

```
{
       "TS": ISODate("2016-08-01T10:09:40.814Z"),
       "user_ques": "how are you?",
       "rep_ans": "i am fine"
    },
     {
       "TS": ISODate("2016-08-04T10:09:55.724Z"),
       "user_ques": "help me",
       "rep_ans": "sure"
    }
    {
       "TS": ISODate("2016-08-09T10:09:00.631Z"),
       "user_ques": "hi",
       "rep_ans": "hello" 
    }
```

instead what i got is expected result plus the field with date 2016-07-24. I wanted to get only result between the specified date. I'm new to mongo. How do I get the expected result?

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

**Edit**

solution provided by Prabhu and Ihor work fine for mongodb client, but I'm not able to translate the same query for pymongo. Can somebody help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate Query as shown below. Edit the query to your required output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
            chat: {
               $elemMatch: 
                 {TS: 
                    {
                        $gt: ISODate('2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
                        $lt: ISODate('2016-08-10T00:00:00.000Z')
                    }
                 }
              } 
            }
        },
       {
          $project: {
             _id:1,             
             chat: {
                $filter: {
                   input: "$chat",
                   as: "item",
                   cond: { 
                       $and: [
                            {$gt: [ "$$item.TS", ISODate('2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z') ]},
                            {$lt: ["$$item.TS", ISODate('2016-08-10T00:00:00.000Z')]}
                       ]
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    ])
```

Comment: Hi @Prabhu i'm getting:
`Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:9)
    at (shell):1:12
Wed Aug 10 16:48:20.377 aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$filter'",
 "code" : 15999,
 "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898`
i feel its due to the version of mongo i'm using, any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi Prashant, You are correct. Starting with the 3.2 release, you can use the new $filter aggregation operator to filter an array during projection, which has the benefit of including all matches, instead of just the first one. Please refer the below URL.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: hey @Prabhu, one more help, it is working fine now in mongo after i updated, but I'm not able to run the query with pymongo, can you please write the query for pymongo, would be a big help.

Comment: hi @PrashantS , sorry but I also don't have any experience with pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered for the same question about searching in array with date range.
Look at [MongoDb searching nested array between dateTimes using Robomongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346432/mongodb-searching-nested-array-between-datetimes-using-robomongo/38347022#38347022)

If it doesn't fit you, I will show you a query with your data.

Comment: hey @Ihor, i was wondering if you help me out by telling the same query in pymongo, i tried it there but throws error.

Comment: hi, sorry but I don't have any experience with pymongo.

Answer (score -2):

```json
db.collection.find({
    'chat.TS':{
        $gte:ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lte:ISODate("2016-08-10T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
},
{'chat.TS':1})
.pretty()
```

Comment: Normal Projection won't work here. This will still show the 07-24 chat object inside the chat array for the first document.